# Running script in Azure WebJob requiring elevated permissions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I have a `function app`, in the `app service` I am adding a `webjob`, which would run a `.cmd` or `.ps1` script for some functionality required by the `function app`. The script requires administrator permissions. I am trying to run the `webjob`, but the `logs` show me the error that admin rights are required. How can I run the `webjob` with elevated permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web Jobs and Function Apps are running on App Service, which is running inside a sandbox. You can't get administrator permissions in App Service.

Read about the limitations and possibilities in [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).